# CodeMirror save itself onBlur

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codemirror

I want to save all CodeMirrors generated by PHP itself onBlur. Here is what I am talking about:

```
        while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
         ...
            var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("id'.$db_field['id'].'"), {
              lineNumbers: true,    
              matchBrackets: true,
              mode: "application/x-httpd-php",    
              onBlur: id'.$db_field['id'].'.save()
            });
         ...
         }
```

But it don´t work ... FireBug says: "id1 is not defined" ... how to do it?

Comment: is there an element present in the DOM with `id=id1`? if yes then try wrapping up your code in `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: show us all code, we don't know how do you mixed html and php there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found bug in my code:

```
        var id'.$db_field['id'].' = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("id'.$db_field['id'].'"), {
        lineNumbers: true,    
        matchBrackets: true,
        mode: "application/x-httpd-php",
        onBlur: function(){
          id'.$db_field['id'].'.save();
        },
        onChange: function(){
        $("#changeimg").show();
        }     
        });
```

This works like a charm